# ReactJS: Why is the convention to fetch data on componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per this link https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html,

I've built a todo app that works great. I fetch my data in `componentDidMount` hook like they say to. I just had a question on the why.

Why do we fetch data after the components mounted? Seems to me it just ends up re-rendering once the data gets set in `setState()` in the hook.

Why not just fetch the data in `constructor()` and set the initial state with data? Wouldn't that be just the 1 render? Seems less expensive even if its only partially re-rendering because of the virtual DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch will generally be executing asynchronously so it's always going to cause a second render despite it being within `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`.

I believe they are recommending to put it within the `componentDidMount` as you may be using a browser dependant implementation of sorts.  When executing/rendering components on the server (i.e. within node) only `componentWillMount` gets executed, and therefore could fall over if you are using a browser/DOM dependant feature.  The other lifecyle methods (i.e. `componentDidMount`) don't get executed on the server, so hence the safety and recommendation I think.  Although in general I have found it more useful when needing to do DOM access.  Use a universal ajax library (i.e. runs on node/browser) and this probably won't be a concern for you.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, didn't think about the lifecycle of components being synchronous

Comment: This is probably the same rationale as to why you can't set in constructor i imagine?

Comment: I would assume so yes.